# How to dynamically add component BEFORE another list element in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say I have a list of items, LI style, like a contact list or to-do things like this:

```
<li data-letter="J">James Taylor</li>
<li data-letter="J">John Connor</li>
<li data-letter="K">Kyle Connor</li>
<li data-letter="P">Peter Parker</li>
```

And I need to dynamically add a letter separator between some of those elements, where the result should be something like this:

```
<separator-component>- J -</separator-component>
<li data-letter="J">James Taylor</li>
<li data-letter="J">John Connor</li>
<separator-component>- K </separator-component>
<li data-letter="K">Kyle Connor</li>
<separator-component>- P -</separator-component>
<li data-letter="P">Peter Parker</li>
```

Using `ViewChildren` I have managed to get the list of `QueryList<ViewContainerRef>` for those LI items, and could add the separator components to them, but only **after** the item I want to insert **BEFORE**.

This is my component template:

```
<li #listItems *ngFor="let element of elements" [attr.data-letter]="element.letter">{{ element.name }}</li>
```

And this is the code (the relevant part of it):

```
@ViewChildren('listItems', {read: ViewContainerRef}) listItems: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

addItem(index: number) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SeparatorComponent);
    const componentRef = this.listItems.toArray()[index].createComponent(componentFactory, 0);

    componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    this.letterRefs.push(componentRef);
}
```

And this is the result I'm getting so far...

```
<li data-letter="J">James Taylor</li>
<separator-component>- J -</separator-component>
<li data-letter="J">John Connor</li>
<li data-letter="K">Kyle Connor</li>
<separator-component>- K </separator-component>
<li data-letter="P">Peter Parker</li>
<separator-component>- P -</separator-component>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) to understand how `createComponent` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements" #listItems>
    <li [attr.data-letter]="element.letter">{{ element.name }}</li>
</ng-container>
```

---

**Edit**: After closer inspection this works because `ng-container` becomes a comment in the DOM before the `li`:

```
<!---->
<li></li>
```

And `createComponent` always renders the new component *after* (not inside) the `ViewContainerRef`, which is the comment in this case.

So it's kind of like doing the following:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements">
   <ng-container #listItems></ng-container>
   <li [attr.data-letter]="element.letter">{{ element.name }}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Also, the `0` in this line can be removed because we don't care about an index anymore:

`this.listItems.toArray()[index].createComponent(componentFactory, 0);`

I actually hope someone has a better answer to this question because it feels like a hack!

Comment: Jezz, this works!! Gonna wait for a couple of days in case somebody comes up with a more polished solution tho, otherwise I'll mark yours as accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the second example so that it won't leave an unused `li` in the DOM. Still not great, but I think the intention of the template is more clear. I'd probably rename `listItems` to `targets` or similar to further clarify its purpose.